# Calling accept() causes WSAEFAULT 10014 Bad address

Tags: c++, c, networking, tcp, winsock2

I'm writing a custom TCP server for Windows, using MinGW compiler and winsock2 API.

I have this piece of code:

```
TCPSocket TCPSocket::accept() {

    TCPSocket clSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in clAddr;
    socklen_t clAddrSize;

    clAddrSize = sizeof(clAddr);

    clSocket.shared->sockFd = ::accept(shared->sockFd, (struct sockaddr *)&clAddr, &clAddrSize);
    if (clSocket.shared->sockFd < 0) {
        printf("failed to accept incoming connection (code: %d)\n", WSAGetLastError());
        throw SocketException(6, "failed to accept incoming connection");
    }

    clSocket.shared->buffer = new byte [BUFFER_SIZE];
    clSocket.shared->curPos = clSocket.shared->endPos = clSocket.shared->buffer;

    return clSocket;

}
```

However after calling accept() i get

```
failed to accept incoming connection (code: 10014)
```

which is according to MSDN:

> WSAEFAULT
>   10014
>   Bad address.
>       The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument of a call. This error occurs if an application
>   passes an invalid pointer value, or if the length of the buffer is too
>   small. For instance, if the length of an argument, which is a sockaddr
>   structure, is smaller than the sizeof(sockaddr).

I don't see, how these pointers can be bad, they both directly address a local variable. The `clAddrSize` is initialized and `shared->sockFd` is initialized in another function

```
void TCPSocket::listen(uint16_t port, int backlog) {

    struct addrinfo * ainfo;
    char portStr[8];
    int res;

    if (shared->sockFd != -1)
        logicError(1, "socket already initialized, need to close first");

    snprintf(portStr, sizeof(portStr), "%hu", (ushort)port);
    if (getaddrinfo("localhost", portStr, NULL, &ainfo) != 0)
        systemError(2, "failed to retrieve info about localhost", false);

    shared->sockFd = socket(ainfo->ai_family, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (shared->sockFd < 0)
        systemError(3, "failed to create a TCP socket", false);

    res = bind(shared->sockFd, ainfo->ai_addr, ainfo->ai_addrlen);
    if (res != 0)
        systemError(5, "failed to bind socket to local port", true);

    res = ::listen(shared->sockFd, backlog);
    if (res != 0)
        systemError(6, "failed to set socket to listen state", true);

    freeaddrinfo(ainfo);

}
```

Do you see anything that i overlooked?

Comment: Smells like corrupted memory management, which happend (way) before this call to `accept()`.

Comment: Does `socklen_t` and `accepts()`'s last argument (as defined by the API you are using)  match in size?

Comment: typedef int socklen_t; WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE SOCKET PASCAL accept(SOCKET,struct sockaddr*,int*);  So yea, it is the same

Comment: You say this: `I don't see, how these pointers can be bad, they both directly address a local variable.`  Then you say this: `shared->sockFd is initialized in another function with socket`.  So the variables are not all local.

Comment: Has `shared->sockFd` been initialise? And had `AF_INET` been used to do so?

Comment: Does it work when doing  `::accept(shared->sockFd, NULL, NULL);`?

Comment: this is interesting: when i use NULLs, it calls the accept() successfully without exiting with error, but this time it never exits out of accept, and connecting client gets 10061 Connection refused

Comment: You might like to show the code to create, bind and make the socket listen, which is expected to be called before calling `accept()`.

Comment: Regarding the client getting `Connection refused`: The client obviously tried to connect to something different then the server was listening for, different host, port or protocol.

Comment: ok, i will edit the question to include the socket initialization

Comment: Are you by any chance listen on IPv6 too? and the `accept` call returns an IPv6 socket (`struct sockaddr_in6`) which is too large to fit in a `struct sockaddr_in` variable? For portability, `struct sockaddr_storage` should be used.

Comment: oh, that's a correct answer, getaddrinfo("localhost") returned IPv6 address and the sockaddr_in is IPv4

Comment: @Youda008: That would certainly fall into the "*... **length of the buffer is too small** ...*" clause of `WSAEFAULT`.  The alternative is to restrict `getaddrinfo()` to IPv4 via its `hints` parameter, if you are not prepared to handle IPv6 correctly.

Comment: Why not anybody does provide an answer for this final solution? You could also provide an answer yourself and also accept it.

Comment: Ok, i will do it, thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so thanks to [CristiFati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4788546/cristifati) i found the problem.
The function getaddrinfo("localhost", portStr, NULL, &ainfo) used that way was returning an IPv6 address. While accept was getting sockaddr_in, which is a struct for IPv4 address.

It could be probably solved more ways, for example

- using sockaddr_in6 for IPv6 communication
- telling getaddrinfo to to search only IPv4 results with 3rd argument
- picking up next result in the linked list returned by getaddrinfo

But i chose to manualy init the socket for IPv4 protocol this way:

```
    struct sockaddr_in myAddr;

    memset(&myAddr, 0, sizeof(myAddr));
    myAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    myAddr.sin_port   = htons((ushort)port);

    shared->sockFd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (shared->sockFd < 0)
        systemError(3, "failed to create a TCP socket", false);

    res = bind(shared->sockFd, (struct sockaddr *)&myAddr, sizeof(myAddr));
    if (res != 0)
        systemError(5, "failed to bind socket to local port", true);
```

Since that, everything works.